# Changing ScrollViews subview dynamically in iOS 8

Tags: swift, ios8, autolayout, scrollview

I'm using a ScrollView in my main page to scroll vertically the content in an view like this (Ipad resolution) :

[image]

For this I set a `View` in the top and another `View` below.

But want I want to do here is change the `View` below to displays to another `View` more bigger if some condition is true, (e.g in the `viewDidLoad()`) and the ScrollView scroll vertically regarding the size of the another `View`, but the size of the another `View` it's the double of the actual , something like the following image :

[image]

Of course the above image only show as I like to see it in general, In this case I wish to grow the `contentSize` of the ScrollView to more higher (in runtime).

My problem here is that when I not set the respective constraints I'm capable to change the `contentSize` as I want, but when I rotate the device my subviews remains in 768 of width, but if I set the autolayout constraints when I rotate the device all work fine , but I can't update the `contentSize` of the ScrollView because it calculate his metrics based in his subviews.

How can I accomplish this behaviour?

There are any other UI better to this than ScrollView?

Comment: Are you saying you want the top view to have a fixed size (say 200) and and then the bottom view has all the rest? I.e. bottom view height = screenHeight - 200?

Comment: @Aggressor Yes the below view has the rest of the height of the ScrollView.

Comment: Can you please explain your bottom paragraphs again? Its not quite clear

Comment: @Aggressor The main goal of the question is how change the contentSize of the ScrollView once the autolayout constraint has set, because when you set another view in the place of older if the contentSize remains in 1024 for example, the rest of the content would not be scrollable and the View is more bigger thant the previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to set it up so that you can scroll vertically, and update the height of the grayView programmatically.

1. Constrain the top, left, right and bottom of the scrollView to the top, left, right, and bottom of the top level view.
2. Constrain the left, top, and right of the orangeView to the left, top, and right of the scrollView.  Constrain the width of the orangeView to be equal to the width of the scrollView.  Set a constraint for the height of the orangeView (say `200`).
3. Constrain the left, bottom, and right of the grayView to the left, bottom, and right of the scrollView.  Constrain the width of the grayView to be equal to the width of the scrollView. Set a constraint for the height of the grayView (say `800`).  Make an `IBOutlet` to this constraint to your code so that you can update its height by changing its `constant` property.  To do this, find the constraint in the *Document Outline* view and control-drag from it to your code to create the IBOutlet.  Give it a name like `grayViewHeight`.  When you want to set it do `grayViewHeight.constant = 1000`.
4. Add a vertical space constraint between the orangeView and the grayView.

Now the content size of your scrollView is fully specified and you can grow it when you need to.  The orangeView and grayView will automatically stretch horizontally to match the width of the scrollView in all orientations.

Comment: Isn't exactly what I looking for , but you answer gave me a nice idea and I solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup delegate for UIScrollView in Storyboard
2. set up AutoLayout/AutoResize for scrollView.
3. then add following code in viewDidLoad() method.

   ```
   var contentRect: CGRect = CGRectZero

   for view: UIView in self.scrollView.subviews
   {
       contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame)
   }
   self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
   scrollView.addSubview(viewtoscroll)
   ```

Then run your app. It is working for each screen size.